# Azure Pipelines for Gradle project fails with Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found PathtoPublish

Tags: spring-boot, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to publish the resulting jar from a Gradle build. The problem I've come across is that the `PublishBuildArtifacts` fails with:

```
##[error]Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found PathtoPublish: /home/vsts/work/1/s/build/libs/sleuth-kafka-streams-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'
```

Here's the whole pipeline definition:

```
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
jobs:
  - job: build
    steps:
    - script: echo Hello, world!
      displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

    - script: |
        echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
        echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
      displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
    - script: pwd
    - script: find ./
    - task: Gradle@2
      inputs:
        gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
        tasks: 'clean build -x test'
        workingDirectory: ''
        publishJUnitResults: false
        testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
        javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
        sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
        sqGradlePluginVersionChoice: 'specify'
        sonarQubeGradlePluginVersion: '2.6.1'
    - script: find ../
    - script: find ../../
    - script: pwd
    - script: echo $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    - script: echo $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) 
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build/libs/sleuth-kafka-streams-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'
        ArtifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'
```

The jar file is actually there as I can see in the output of the different `find` scripts, e.g.:

```
find ../../
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/3ff8a757-49a9-4769-b65f-72282d823867.sh
...
../../1/s/build/libs/sleuth-kafka-streams-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I also tried using `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` as the begining of the path, `PathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/build/libs/sleuth-kafka-streams-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'`.

In this case the error is:

```
##[warning]Directory '/home/vsts/work/1/a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'
```

Can you see what's wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason I had to add a `CopyFiles` task to make it work:

```
        - task: CopyFiles@2
          inputs:
            contents: '**/*.jar'
            targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
          inputs:
            ArtifactName: 'drop'
            publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could accept it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.Have a good day